# I am getting a TypeError: First argument must be string or compiled object when I am pretty certain that the first object of my re.sub is

Tags: python, regex

I am currently writing a program to modify offset values for a robot and these values are stored in a Program in text form. I have managed to get most of the functionality complete, but I am having problems with this last function. It's the re.sub method. I keep getting an error saying:
raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern.

However to me it seems that the first argument is a compiled pattern. Could use some help trying to figure this out, if anyone has any advice. Here is the portion that is having the issue. Its the submit_x_offset function. Also is seems to delete the whole file and also that same regex statement works just fine in find_x_offset where it is not currently compiled.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import re


class Controller(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6, sticky=W)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (ChooseFile, GusToPlateRight, GusToPlateLeft):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        self.show_frame(ChooseFile)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class ChooseFile(tk.Frame):

    def open_file(self):
        global filename

        file.delete('1.0', END)

        userentry_fname.delete('0', END)

        f_types = [("FLW Programs", "*.ls"), ("Text Files ", "*.txt")]

        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=f_types)

        userentry_fname.insert(END, filename)

        my_file = open(filename).read()

        file.insert(END, my_file)

    def clear_file(self):
        file.delete('1.0', END)
        userentry_fname.delete('0', END)

    def find_x_offsets(self, xoffset_match):
        # global matches

        xoffset_match.delete('1.0', END)
        with open(filename, 'r') as text:
            string = text.read()
            matches = re.search(
                r'!GUSSET TO BACKPLATE RIGHT GUS 1.*PR\[GP1:2,1:OFFSET\]=([^; ]*)(?!ENDFOR).*ENDFOR.*', string,
                re.M | re.DOTALL)
            print(matches.group(1))

            xoffset_match.insert(END, matches.group(1))

    def submit_x_offsets(self, set_xoffset):
        text_to_replace = set_xoffset.get()
        offset_to_change = re.compile(
            r'!GUSSET TO BACKPLATE RIGHT GUS 1.*PR\[GP1:2,1:OFFSET\]=([^; ]*)(?!ENDFOR).*ENDFOR.*', re.M | re.S).groups

        with open(filename, 'r') as text:
            string = text.read()
        with open(filename, 'w') as file:
            string = re.sub(offset_to_change, text_to_replace, string)
            file.write(string.group(1))
```

Comment: why you are adding .groups at the end while assigning offset_to_change?

Comment: re.sub() returns a string and string does not have any group() method associated with it. Moreover, on the line offset_to_change = re.compile(...).groups no longer just remain compile pattern. .groups returns 'int'. Hence it is throwing an error that first argument should be a string or compile pattern because you are passing 'int'.

Comment: So I can't use groups with re.sub? If so that changes the a lot about the way I need to go about this. However I have tried it without groups as well and it's throwing other errors when i try to compile. I will read up some more see what I can figure out. I might just have to do something else for that function is all.

Comment: describe what you actually want to do. re.sub() returns string replaced after finding the pattern, so there is no groups associated with it. You can use groups() method to find the specific group matching you are looking for. Check example of [groups](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm)

Comment: You see how the find_x_offset method works and it finds the specific group in between !GUSSET TO BACKPLATE RIGHT GUS 1 AND ENDFOR by searching for group 1, (^; ). Well I need to accomplish that same thing with re.sub. I have seen some examples of how to right re.sub with groups etc. I was hoping I could use the same regex without the .group on the end and have it replace the string instead of just match it thats all. It will be changed to a value entered into another entrybox

Comment: re.search() is to search, re.sub() is to search and replace. What you want is to search, then use only re.search().

Answer (score 0):

I think I explained that wrong. I want to sub out the same line that I searched for in find_x_offset. I need to replace one number with another. The search function I make work just fine. No issues. I need a sub or replace function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the first part of your regex pattern, but in the entire regex pattern. In other words, there's an error in the pattern and it's telling you in a rather unhelpful way.

The message - "first argument must be string or compiled object" refers to the first argument to the re function, which is the string or object you feed it.

It can be that what you supplied is not a string or compiled object. But it is also possible there is actually an error in the pattern, like a missing bracket on a capture group, for example.